# Regular expression string only with limit

Tags: c#, regex

I'm learning to create regex queries on string with a limit of 30 characters (mainly use for First name and Last Name)

I'm using asp.net C#
but I don't seem to find it correct with the codes I'm writing

```
[WebMethod]   
public bool stringOnlyAndLimit(String strToCheck) 
{
    Regex stringonly = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z]{1,30}"); 
    return !stringonly.IsMatch(strToCheck);
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `"^[a-zA-Z ]{1,30}$"`

Comment: If you want first *and* last name, changes are your regex needs to include `\s` for the space.

Comment: So the name `O'Malley` isn't valid?

Comment: More generally, there are a _lot_ of variations on names, especially when you start looking at different cultures, so don't expect to be able to handle 100% of cases without alienating some portion of your users if you do some simple validation like that.

Comment: I would definitely keep the validation loose and just check the `Length`, as @TimS points out, names can vary greatly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to learn RegEx then ignore this answer, otherwise

**A Non-RegEx option.**
You don't need Regex for something like that, you can do:

```
public bool stringOnlyAndLimit(String strToCheck)
{
 return strToCheck.Length < 31 && strToCheck.All(r => char.IsLetter(r));        
 //return strToCheck.Length < 31 && !strToCheck.Any(r => char.IsDigit(r));
}
```

**With RegEX**

```
public static bool stringOnlyAndLimit(String strToCheck)
{
    Regex stringonly = new Regex("^[a-zA-Z ]{1,30}$");
    return stringonly.IsMatch(strToCheck);
}
```

Comment: This Question is tagged as regex. So regex should be an answer. he might want to learn it deeper.

Comment: @RoyiNamir, I have seen lots of question with RegEx tag, where OP not knowing in first place, that may be RegEx is not the right tool.

Comment: can u explain me what is the "r => char.IsDigit(r)"

Comment: @Habib, would it make more sense to put the length check outside the `Any`?

Comment: this allows allows characters like `[]'#£$` etc, and the intent is less clear than a regex, maintainers will simply wonder why you didn't use one

Comment: @Habib, For what Robert said, would it also make sense to use char.IsLetter()?

Comment: @RobertByrne, thanks, OP can change that as well, I have left both the options in the answer

Comment: @Habib no problem, I would also put a `String.IsNullOrEmpty`/`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace` check at the top

Comment: @RobertByrne, yup, I would let the OP add that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:-

```
^[a-zA-Z ]{1,30}$
```

Answer (score 1):

Your regular expression `[^a-zA-Z]{1,30}` currently says give me anything that is NOT the letters a-z & A-Z because of the carrot `^` within the brackets.  Remove this and it will work for a single string with no white space.

If you want to check for first and last name with one RegEx including the space character and be under 30 characters it should be something like this:

`^[a-zA-Z\s]{1,30}$`

Comment: You can (and should) put the `\s` inside the character class: `[a-zA-Z\s]`.  And it's *caret*, not *carrot*. ;)

Comment: Carrots taste better though

Answer (score 0):

Not particularly for C#, ^ is a *NOT* sign inside brackets. So [^abc] will match any character **except** a, b, or c.

So your regex should be [a-zA-Z]{1,30}

Answer (score 0):

Try this regular expression

```
^[A-Za-z]{0,30}$
```